# auth_type=reauthenticate(in FB login URL) not asking user to enter PASSWORD if they are previously logged-in. I am using PHP SDK

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, facebook-login

I am using PHP SDK to manage my application. So if user clicks on my custom login button they must be asked to **enter their login credentials** whether they are previously logged-in.

Application was login-in to the user through method `getLoginUrl()`, but it never ask to **reauthenticate** if user is previously logged-in. We have already set `Force Web OAuth Reauthentication` to `Yes` in FB login settings.

I am trying to login like this:

```php
$helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();
$permissions = ['manage_pages','publish_pages'];
$loginUrl = $helper->getReAuthenticationUrl(fb-callback-url.php', $permissions);
```

The `getReAuthenticationUrl()` method is generating login URL like:

https://www.facebook.com/v2.9/dialog/oauth?auth_type=reauthenticate&client_id=xxxxxx...

I expect that above FB login URL will ask user to provide login credentials whether they are previously logged-in.

But still it's not asking to enter user login details if user is previously logged-in and it directly take the user to accept APP T&C. Our FB APP is pending to be approved because of this issue.

Comment: Works for me, when I just add `auth_type=reauthenticate` to the login dialog URL triggered from Graph API Explorer.

Comment: Were you already logged-in to FB before testing and again you need to be authorized when you add "auth_type=reauthenticate".? Can you please share me final URL with "auth_type=reauthenticate"

Comment: Is there someone who can help?